# How to perform a user input check with multiple fields of a Django model?

Tags: django

Let me start by saying that I am new to the world of programming and since August of this year I have started to study Python and then Django by myself. I'm trying to implement a view for which if you are authenticated as a Django user and if you enter a key and a phone number that match the one registered in the database then you have access to a specific URL resource.

The steps would be as follows: On the Homepage there is a button that, if clicked, redirects to the access_to_events_by_secret view that instantiates the form with the two fields to be filled in. Then the user enters the data and at that point the entered data is verified and if it matches the phone number and key in the database then you are redirected to a specific URL.

Here's the code:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .utils import generate_code
# Create your models here.


class Secret(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.key == "":
            self.key = generate_code()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Utils.py

```
import uuid


def generate_code():
    code = uuid.uuid4()
    code_mod = str(code).replace('-', '').upper()[:15]
    return code_mod
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Secret

class SecretModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Secret
        fields = ["phone_number", "key"]
        widgets = {"key": forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Inserisci la chiave segreta.."})}
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import SecretModelForm
from .models import Secret

def homepage(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'core/homepage.html', context)

def access_to_events_by_secret(request):
    keys = Secret.objects.order_by('key')
    phone_numbers = Secret.objects.order_by('phone_number')
    form = SecretModelForm()
    context = {"form": form, "keys": keys, "phone_numbers": phone_numbers}
    if request.method == "POST":
        instance_k = Secret.objects.get(key=request.POST['key'])
        instance_p_n = Secret.objects.get(phone_number=request.POST['phone_number'])
        form = SecretModelForm(request.POST, instance_k=instance_k, instance_p_n=instance_p_n)
        if form.is_valid():
            if request.POST.get("key").strip() == instance_k.key and request.POST.get("phone_number").strip() == instance_p_n.phone_number:
                return redirect("/events/")

    return render(request, "core/secret_access.html", context)
```

Secret_access.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}{{ block.super }} -  Secret{% endblock head_title %}
{% block content %}
    
        <div class="container">
                <h1 class="text-light text-center mt-5">Secret Access</h1>
               
                <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-auto d-flex justify-content-center">
                         <form method="POST" novalidate>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.key }} 
                            {{ form.phone_number }}
                            <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{ key }}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="phone_number" value="{{ phone_number }}" />
                            <div class="container text-center">
                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" value="Accedi!">
                            </div>
                          </form>
                     </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        
{% endblock content %}
```

Any help would be really much appreciated!!

Comment: Questions here need to be in English. Aside from that: (based on a quick google-translate) you haven't asked a specific question. You posted a set of requirements, and some code, but... it's unclear what your question is. Please edit to 1) be in English and 2) provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for translating your question. Unfortunately, it is too broad and unclear. Do you have a _specific_ question about the code you've shared? Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)